# Decorator Operation not allowed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, cdi

I have a decorator on an EJB (so this decorator is CDI if I understand it correct). I need do some business logic depending on the role the logged in user is. So in the EJB I have the SessionContext, but since this is an EJB object, I need to look it up via JNDI.

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
SessionContext ctx = (SessionContext) ic.lookup("java:comp/EJBContext");
```

This works, but creates another error. When I try to call `ctx.isCallerInRole("MyRole");` I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Operation not allowed
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.SessionContextImpl.checkAccessToCallerSecurity(SessionContextImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContextImpl.isCallerInRole(EJBContextImpl.java:447)
    at com.example.decorators.MyDecorator.findAll(MyDecorator.java:46)
```

What I expect is happening is that a CDI is not allowed to ask the SessionContext if the logged in user is in the specified role. Is there a way how I can solve this? I've been roaming Google for a few days now, without success.

Erates

**Edit:**

This is what I have at the moment:

Interface:

```
@Local
public interface StatelessSessionBeanLocal extends Serializable {
    <T> Collection<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz);
    boolean isCallerInRole(String role);
}
```

EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessSessionBean implements StatelessSessionBeanLocal {
    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

    @Override
    public <T> Collection<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz){
       ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCallerInRole(String role){
        return ctx.isCallerInRole(role);
    }
}
```

Decorator:

```
@Decorator
public abstract class StatelessSessionBeanDecorator implements StatelessSessionBeanLocal {
    @Inject
    @Delegate
    StatelessSessionBeanLocal sb;

    @Override
    public <T> Collection<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz){
        if (sb.isCallerInRole("TestRole")){
            return new ArrayList();
        } else {
            return sb.findAll(clazz);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a NullPointerException at StatelessSessionBean.isCallerInRole pointing to the fact that the SessionContext is not injected. (I think because of the difference between SessionContext (EJB) and Inject (CDI)) Note, the EJB and Decorator are in different packages in different JARs in the EAR.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was a Classloader issue.

```
ear
| - lib
|    | - custom decorators.jar
| - custom ejb
| - ejb
| - war
```

I used a producer class that creates the EntityManager and SessionContext using the `@Produces` annotations on them. This producer class was in the "ejb" jar. On the decorators I used a `provided` dependency to the "ejb" so at that point, it knew where the `@Inject` would come from.

But once in runtime, the custom EJB would find the decorator because it is in the libs folder, but the decorator could not find the `Produced` `SessionContext` or `EntityManager`.

Now I've moved the decorators inside the "custom ejb" and all works just fine and dandy.

Answer (score 0):

The SessionContext is created for each bean instance, with the lookup approach you didn't obtain the ctx bind to your bean instance so the method is not allowed. 
Try using @Resource injection to obtain the bean context.

Comment: Well.. the @Resource is EJB (as far as I know), and since this bean is a decorator (CDI) it doesn't inject it. Result --> NullPointerException

Comment: SessionContext is an EJB spec interface, ejbs are cdi bean, try to define your decorator as a [@Stateless bean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html#bnbxu)

Comment: If I do that, Netbeans complains that a Stateless bean should not be annotated with Decorator or Interceptor. So when I remove the Decorator annotation Netbeans complains that the Delegate annotation should not be in a Stateless bean. So when I do that, the whole purpose of the decorator is gone. Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Define @Stateless your bean impl and injext SessionContext there, then define a method delegate to ctx.isCallerInRole. In your decorator inject the bean related instance with Inject Delegate Any MyBean myBean and call the delegated method

Comment: Ok, so I now have a method - `boolean isCallerInRole(String role);` exposed in the Interface, that both (the bean and the decorator) implement. Only the bean overrides it, requests the SessionContext (which has the `@Resource` annotation) if the caller is in the role. Now the NPE is gone in the decorator, but appeared at the `isCallerInRole(String role)` method of the bean itself.

Comment: @maress I've updated the question with the current code

Comment: On the delegate, why dont you do an EJB injection rather than a CDI injection on the delegate point? Besides, since this is a role based check, why dont you just annotate the ejb bean or its method with the @RoleAllowed annotation?

Comment: @maress I cannot do an EJB injection on the delegate, because the `@Decorator` requires a CDI delegate injection. I cannot annotate the EJB bean with `@RolesAllowed` because the EJB bean is in my main project, and depending on the extension, different roles get to see different things. For example, I need to get a list from a database, but depending on the role the user is in, some objects from that list are removed (or not retrieved from DB). So putting the `@RolesAllowed` on the decorator is no option either.